# Flink set parallelism of 3, but only one host is used

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a job that when I run without setting the parallelism (parallelism=1 by default) processes about 40 elements a second. It has an asyncIO function in it which is the slowest part. So I want to increase the parallelism of the job as a whole to increase performance. I select the job to run from the Flink cluster's GUI and set the parallelism to 3 and it shows each part of the job having a parallelism of 3.

Now here is where I run into the problem.

Each part of the job (each map function, and the asyncIO function) shows the 3 task slots it has and even has them on each one on a different slave node:

[image]

But when data comes through it only uses a single task slot. And instead of performance increasing it decreases significantly (guessing because it is now maintaining connections between the parallel task slots but not actually using them to increase performance). So to reference the above screenshot, all the data is ran through flink-1 and nothing goes through flink-2 or flink-3. And this is the case on each flatmap and the asyncIO function (so not that on flatmap-00 runs data through flink-1, asyncIO-0 uses flink-2, they both use flink-1).

Is there something I am missing? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What kind of source are you using? I believe this may happen if you have a one that is inherently non-parallel. In that case a rebalance() after the source may solve your problem.

Comment: not using rebalance() solved it. Thanks!